# CUDA: reindexing arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda, indexing

In this example, I have 3 float arrays, query_points[], initial_array[], and final_array[]. Values in query_points[] are rounded down and become index values, and I want to copy the data at those indexes in initial_array[] to result_array[].

The problem I'm having is every few hundred values, I am getting different values compared to properly working c++ code. I am new to CUDA and not sure what is happening. Please let me know if you can point me towards a solution. Thanks!

CUDA Code:

```
int w = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; // Col // width
int h = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y; // Row // height
int index = h*width+w;

if ((w < width) && (h < height)){
    int piece = floor(query_points[index]) - 1;
    int piece_index = h*width+piece;

    result_array[index] = initial_array[piece_index];
}
```

Comment: Please provide a short, complete compilable code, that demonstrates the issue/mismatch.  SO expects this: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)".  Have you run your code with `cuda-memcheck` ?

Comment: @RobertCrovella I wasn't sure how to create a minimal example since it required large arrays for the error to occur. The code worked fine on minimal arrays. Cuda-memcheck showed 0 errors. Strangely, the issue stopped occurring after I rebooted the system, and now seems to be working fine, though I am still skeptical about its reliability. I also think it may have had to do with the fact that I was passing the same input and output array into the function, trying to do an in place operation.

Comment: "I also think it may have had to do with the fact that I was passing the same input and output array into the function, trying to do an in place operation."  Yes, that could be a problem, and it was not at all evident either from the code you posted or your question/description, which certainly made it sound like the 3 arrays are distinct.  Providing a *complete* code would have clarified that you are actually doing things in-place.  If you're unable/unwilling to provide a complete code, your question just provokes a lot of speculation, and is not a good fit for SO, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You gave the answer in your own comment: "I also think it may have had to do with the fact that I was passing the same input and output array into the function, trying to do an in place operation."

Your description of the symptom (it only happens occasionally and it only repros on large arrays) also fits the explanation.

Note that it isn't always possible to guard against race conditions if you want full concurrency - you may have to use separate input and output arrays.  Merge Sort and Radix Sort both ping-pong between intermediate arrays while processing.  I don't think anyone has figured out how to implement those algorithms without O(N) auxiliary space.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't write the code to test it but there are two problems that I can see:

1. If you are floor-ing a float than use floorf() function. I do not think this is the cause, but it is obviously the better way to do it.
2. The main issue that I can see is subtler, or maybe I am just speculating: floor() and floorf() return float and double respectively. So, when you do :

   floor(query_points[index]) - 1;

what you have is still a float and might be smaller than the actual integral value you are supposed to get due to precision loss. When you implicitly cast it to integer by

```
int piece = floor(query_points[index]) - 1;
```

you basically truncate the decimal part and get n-1 where you think you are getting n.

Even without this analysis

```
int piece = floor(query_points[index]) - 1;
```

In this line, you are flooring and than truncating, which are essentially the same thing, so you do not even need to use floor() or floorf().

Comment: for what values of x does floor(x) return a value "smaller than the actual integral value you are supposed to get" ?  Or, if you prefer, using the given line of code `int piece = floor(query_points[index]) - 1;`, can you provide any numerical values for the variables on the right hand side, to illustrate getting a value "smaller than the actual integral value you are supposed to get due to precision loss" ?  `floor()` returns a double quantity.  The range of integers that can be precisely represented in a `double` quantity is larger than the range of integers that can be represented by `int`.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I will adjust my code to use floorf and attempt to cast as int if I see the issue reoccur. I am not sure if this was the main problem, as the code would have correct values for maybe 500 entries, then incorrect for about 100, more or less repeat in that pattern (though not exactly regular).